# Mobile-friendly jQuery slider, without bundling an entire mobile library?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-slider

I have a working web application that makes use of the [jQuery UI default slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).

I'm getting complaints from users that the sliders don't work well on mobile (seems you have to tap, rather than drag, to get them to work).

Does anyone know a jQuery slider plugin that works well on mobile?

Obviously I could use the [slider in the jQuery Mobile framework](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/slider/), or another mobile library, but I'm unwilling to add an entire mobile framework to my site just for the sake of one slider!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: check this: http://trentrichardson.com/2011/11/11/jquery-ui-sliders-and-touch-accessibility/

Comment: That looks good - plus/minus buttons probably work better on small screens than even touch events. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertDondo if you submit it as an answer I will accept...

Answer (score 4):

I am aware that this is an old thread but in case anyone comes across it now I would highly recommend using [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/). It works well on mobiles and is really simple to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Swiper.js is very useful when it comes to mobile slider. It has vast amount of features and it is very flexible.